# Is it possible to sort mysql query by OR order

Tags: mysql

I would like to order my results of a query following the order of where clause.

For example, i have this query :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM config_ban_num 
 WHERE 
     ( adresse_seo LIKE '12-rue-de-rivoli%' 
    OR adresse_seo LIKE '13-rue-de-rivoli%' 
    OR adresse_seo LIKE '11-rue-de-rivoli%' ) 
   AND (postcode='75004')
```

When i print the results, i've got this :

```
11-rue-de-rivoli
12-rue-de-rivoli
13-rue-de-rivoli
```

I would like this order regarding the order in where clause :

```
12-rue-de-rivoli
13-rue-de-rivoli
11-rue de rivoli
```

Comment: I do not see much **order** in output you show as desired.

Comment: See FIELD().....

Comment: where's the order in your output? it's scrambled

Comment: There is some order to them. They are returned in the same ordered he passes them to the WHERE clause.

Comment: I provided a sample, though in my solution he must manually configure the ordering with `CASE WHEN`. I can't find another solution, since the order he uses in `WHERE` doesn't follow any specific order logic, for what I could see.

Answer (score 1):

One option is using a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *,
      CASE WHEN adresse_seo LIKE '12-rue-de-rivoli%' THEN 1
           WHEN adresse_seo LIKE '13-rue-de-rivoli%' THEN 2
           WHEN adresse_seo LIKE '11-rue-de-rivoli%' THEN 3
           ELSE 4 END as Position
      FROM config_ban_num 
     WHERE 
         ( adresse_seo LIKE '12-rue-de-rivoli%' 
        OR adresse_seo LIKE '13-rue-de-rivoli%' 
        OR adresse_seo LIKE '11-rue-de-rivoli%' ) 
       AND (postcode='75004')
) SubQuery

ORDER BY Position
```

Comment: perfect ! thnks

Answer (score 1):

Use [MySQL's FIELD function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

```
SELECT * 
FROM config_ban_num 
WHERE adresse_seo in ('12-rue-de-rivoli%', '13-rue-de-rivoli%', '11-rue-de-rivoli%') 
AND (postcode='75004')
ORDER BY FIELD(adresse_seo, '12-rue-de-rivoli%', '13-rue-de-rivoli%', '11-rue-de-rivoli%')
```

Comment: Very nice, I wasn't aware of this function. Is it possible to combine with other possible fields (chaining order clauses), like `ORDER BY FIELD(adresse_seo, '12-rue-de-rivoli%'), FIELD(postcode, 'something')`?

Comment: Also, it looks this function returns **zero** when the string is not found, though it wouldn't be a problem in this scenario, because all rows will have one of the possible 3 strings (due to `WHERE` clause).

Comment: You can add multiple FIELD orders albeit i haven't tested how it will behave. You can even combine it with normal order by clauses.

Comment: Nice, I upvoted your answer, because I think it's better than mine.

Comment: is it quicker to execut than your's alisson ?

Comment: @Vince I can't answer because I don't know the performance of `FIELD`, but it avoids the subquery, so it looks simpler. I'd suggest trying both and choosing what best fits your needs.